# add server name before filename with uname -n

Tags: bash

Here is my command in my script:

```
mv -f -v $oldfile /infanass/dev/admin/backup/${oldfile##*/}_$(date +%F-%T)
```

Right now the output is:

```
file1.txt_2013-07-11-15:08:16
```

I want the server name to show up before the file name. I think :

```
uname -n
```

is the right command but i just can't get it to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use backticks (`` ` ``) before and after `uname -n` to insert the output of this command.

This should do it:

```
mv -f -v $oldfile /infanass/dev/admin/backup/\`uname -n\`${oldfile##*/}_$(date +%F-%T)
```

Comment: [Backticks are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/1655874). You should use capture shells instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
$ mv -f -v $oldfile /infanass/dev/admin/backup/$(uname -n)${oldfile##*/}_$(date +%F-%T)
```